# Tomee + H2 embedded mode + maven : Database may be already in use

Tags: maven, h2, apache-tomee

I am trying to use Maven Tomee plugin (mvn tomee:run) to deploy my app. However when I run this target,I am getting org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use. I am sure that this problem would go away if go server mode route. But I am interested in knowing why the database is getting locked as there should only be one JVM accessing this db.

Snippet of tomee.xml

```
<Resource jndi="test_DS" id="test_DS" type="DataSource">
  JdbcDriver = org.h2.Driver
  JdbcUrl = jdbc:h2:C:\\test\\target\\webui-1.0-SNAPSHOT\\WEB-INF\\classes\\test_db2
  UserName = sa
  Password = sa
</Resource>
```

I am sure this is the only place where I am access the H2 database.

Comment: Before you run it, is there a `test_db2.lock.db` file? If you remove it, does it get re-created automatically? If yes then there must be a process that creates this file: is it the process where the database is open. Check for Java processes using `jps -l`.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller I have been searching for that file. But I don't see it in C:\\test\\target\\webui-1.0-SNAPSHOT\\WEB-INF\\classes\\test_db2. I see that there are two java processes, one is for maven i guess and the other is tomee

Comment: Here is the output for jps -l    C:\Windows\System32>jps -l
6012 sun.tools.jps.Jps     
12228 C:\DevPrograms\Eclipse\Luna\Luna_64\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_
1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar     
5808 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
1176 org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

Comment: I added FILELOCK=FILE; to the URL and I can confirm that it is the tomee which is creating this file each time I delete it. So did anyone get their webapp working with TOMEE with a DB resource configured ? The below is the exact exception    SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-180]
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)

Comment: Which file is created, and why and how do you delete it? The description on what you do is not clear to me. Also, I suggest to try a different directory, for example `C:\temp\data`, to rule out it's an access rights problem.

Comment: @Thomas I am using H2 1.4.180 which I read doesn't create *.db.lock files. So to create these lock files I changed the JDBC URL to include FILELOCK=FILE; I cleaned project,launched tomee:run again. This time I saw *.db.lock in the DB directory. Out of curiosity I deleted *db.lock file manually, but it was created almost instantly. I deleted this lock file multiple times and observed same behavior. But if I kill tomee java process,delete *.db.lock it doesn't get created any more. If tomee is creating this *db.lock file, and it is the only jvm accessing this db, why am i getting db in use ?

Comment: Possibly TomEE is using multiple classloaders, so H2 can't re-use the same database object, and is running as it would be a separate process. If that's really the case (you may have to ask at the TomEE mailing list), then a workaround might be to use the H2 automatic mixed mode (see the docs for details).

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the answer after burning mid-night oil. In the tomee.xml, I acutally had

```
 <Resource jndi="test_DS" id="test_DS" type="DataSource">
  JdbcDriver = org.h2.Driver
  JdbcUrl = jdbc:h2:C:\\test\\target\\webui-1.0-SNAPSHOT\\WEB-INF\\classes\\test_db2
  UserName = sa
  Password = sa
  InitialSize = 5
 </Resource>
```

The IntialSize=5 is one that is causing grief in embedded mode of H2. The default value in tomee for this parameter is 0, but during my testing I changed this to 5. I am still not sure why it would say 'Database is locked by another process', since it is the same 'tomee' process that would create these initial 5 connections if any. If some one could answer this, that would helpful. I also observed that if I shutdown tomee (ctrl c or ctrl z on command line),H2 removes the *.lock.db but if I kill tomee process in process explorer the lock file isn't removed. Would DBStarter help in this case ?